# Shared host, PHP CLI too old to run CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm attempting to run migrations on my shared host (ie. 1and1) and I'm getting an error.

```
(uiserver):me:~/projects/hc$ bin/cake migrations migrate
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/path/to/projects/hc/bin/cake.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/path/to/projects/hc/bin/cake.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
```

Here is the PHP version:

```
(uiserver):me:~/projects/hc$ php --version
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Nov  9 2016 14:11:21)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
```

`phpinfo()` from my browser reveals version 7 (it's what I pay for).

However, from the CLI, it seems to show 4.4.9? Is this a typical setup? Unless I'm mistaken, the source code requires at least CLI 5.5.9.

What are my options?

Comment: ***ABORT MISSION***

Comment: Is there a php5 or php7 executable available from the CLI?

Comment: I have shell access, couldn't I download the latest and run it from there?

Comment: Jumping ship... looking at VPS' now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are my options?

Is that *really* not obvious? Upgrade the php version. Or use an ancient version of the framework that works with php4. :-P

Read these three pages

- http://php.net/eol.php
- http://php.net/supported-versions.php
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements

If your hoster can't do that move to another cheap shared hoster that provides a modern php version that is not ancient, insecure and unsupported. There are enough others to choose from.

Or go for vpscheap.net or digitalocean.com and get a cheap Vserver. I'm paying $12 USD every quarter for more power than I currently need.

Comment: I'll check with my host to see if this can be modified. I didn't think of the CLI when choosing my host. And DigitalOcean refer to VPS as Droplets? In my defence, I was hoping that CLI version, somehow, didn't match the PHP version it used :)

Comment: Yes, I prefer VPS because of the ease of deployment and working with it compared to moving files with (S)FTP. Also I'm in control of my system and can install what I want when I need it. The downside is that you'll have to maintain your server, which I dislike as well, but the advantages are bigger for me.

Comment: I don't think managing the server would be an issue. I wasn't aware they weren't that expensive.